# How to drop packets when a container is not available instead of sending a RST?

Tags: networking, docker

I have a very specific issue with hardware that connects to a containerized service.

When the service is down, the TCP/IP stack is sending back `RST` packets to that service (via the docker `iptables`). I would like the packets to be dropped instead of that (= no response sent, the hardware will timeout).

**Is there a way to configure such behaviour in docker?**

Comment: You need a firewall for that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: `docker` ultimately manages `iptables` so I was hoping for a configuration that would go to that depth.